# Why might Amazon login result in the error "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"

Tags: tls, firefox

Last night I entered my credentials to log into my Amazon account (using Firefox v.50.1.0) and got the error shown below.

An error occurred during a connection to www.amazon.com:80. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: **SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG**

[image: amazon.com login error]

After seeing above error I entered amazon.com into the address field of a new tab, and it seemed like I was already logged in. Being that it was late Friday night I thought perhaps Amazon was making some changes on their site and this was just a temporary problem that would disappear on its own.

But this morning I am getting the same error when I log in to Amazon. And still the same behavior, in that if I just ignore it and navigate to amazon.com afterwards, it looks like I am already logged in.

However I have only seen it on one computer in the household.

So the question I wanted to ask is if this error can be caused by some configuration on my local machine?

**[UPDATE:]** Thank you all for your explanations. The error does seem to result from having the port 80 specified in the address, although I did not enter it on my own.

After attempting to replicate this multiple times, it seems that this happens at the end of the following sequence of steps:

1. Navigate to amazon.com (the browser should be directed to
   https:www.amazon.com)

*[Note that I have only been able to replicate this with a particular version of an Amazon home page as described further down below]*

2. Click on Accounts & Lists > Sign In. Amazon will redirect your
   browser to [this URL](https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%3A80%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dnav_signin) (this URL contains additional redirection
   that will be completed once you enter the credentials and click Sign
   In).
3. Enter credentials and click Sign In.
4. Amazon redirects to the URL specifying the insecure port 80,
   resulting in the error message.

During my attempts to replicate this I noticed that Amazon currently serves at least two different home pages. The more frequent home page has these menu options in the upper right corner:

[image: amazon home page version 1]

The second (less frequent) home page version has more options in the upper right corner and looks like this:

[image: amazon home page version 2]

The login option in this latter version redirects to the URL in step 2 above. That URL is what sets the address to amazon.com:80, leading to the error message.

Comment: Just encountered this myself and was quite puzzled by it. Thanks for such a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are connecting to `https://www.amazon.com:80/`. Your browser expects a SSL handshake to take place because of the `https` protocol part. But the website actually serves a plain HTTP response because you also explicitly specified port 80, the default port for unencrypted HTTP.

Firefox is therefore misinterpreting the HTTP response as malformed SSL traffic which only accidentally looks like a "too long RX record".  The error should be gone if you type in  `https://www.amazon.com/` or `https://www.amazon.com:443/`. (Port 443 is the default for HTTPS.)

You can provoke similar behavior with many other sites. Here is how Chrome similarly yields a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when visiting `https://google.com:80/`:

[image]

Comment: thanks Arminius for the explanation. Although in this case I did not enter the ":80" part in the URL on my own (I have updated my OP with an explanation).

Answer (score 1):

Https connection is usually using port 443, and Http is using 80.
This happens when you try to connect with an insecure connection (without SSL on port 80), while your browser settings only allow secure connection for this site (with SSL on port 443).
Removing ":80" from URL should fix this.